# Clean dataset with many dfferent words for one thing

Tags: database, dataset, data-science, data-cleaning

At the moment I have a dataset of ingredients. The problem is that it is not very clean because it contains many different names for the same thing. Here are a few examples:

Mehl = Weizenmehl, Mehl Type360

or

Eier = Eier, Ei(er), Ei

I thought of maybe deleting those brackets and making many if statements which are looking for different things like "Mehl" but there I would have to also look for something like "Dinkel" because of

Dinkelmehl != Mehl

I could do it but it would be very laborious because that's a big dataset. Are there some other methods maybe with a dictionary or something? I hope you can help me thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frederick!

Yes, you can use map method from pandas. First, I would suggest to clean special characters (!"#$%&/) and the use the map for Eier,Ei, Mehl, Tomaten....

I attach the documentation of map: [map in df pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

VG